# Access the SIM Card with an Android Application?

Tags: android, smartcard, sim-card

I wonder if it's possible to access to the SIM card with an Android Application

Comment: You need to ask much more specific questions. What is it about the SIM card that you want to access?

Comment: Probably "exchange arbitrary APDU-s" is what he wants.

Comment: I want to cimmunicate with a javacard application with APDu or BIP protocol

Answer (score 9):

You can get the IMEI like this (but is it what you want ?), just an exemple :

```
mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

Likewise, you have

```
String getSimCountryIso():
```

Returns the ISO country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.

`String  getSimOperator():` Returns the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the provider of the SIM.

`String  getSimOperatorName():` Returns the Service Provider Name (SPN).

`String  getSimSerialNumber():` Returns the serial number of the SIM, if applicable.

`int     getSimState():` Returns a constant indicating the state of the device SIM card.

`String  getSubscriberId():` Returns the unique subscriber ID, for example, the IMSI for a GSM phone.

For more, take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

and don't forget to add the correct permission in the manifest (`getDeviceId() => Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE`)

Comment: IMEI is associated with the phone device, not the SIM card.

Comment: But Can I send APDU command to the SIM Card to communicate with a javacard application?

Comment: This is an SmartCard Communication Framework, which doesn't let you change the telephonenumber.

Comment: can i get the `scaddress` for SMSManager using it?

Answer (score 5):

Without SmartCardAPI from SEEK(Secure Element Evaluation Kit) its never possible. In majority Android phones available in market SmartCardAPI is not implemented. So either you build your own Android after integrating the SmartCardAPI code or wait for some decent phone with this feature to come out. You can find the patch file for implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount+UploadedBy).

Answer (score 4):

SmartCard API for Android might be of interest for you:
http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/

Comment: Does this app allow you to change MSISDN (phone number) on Android smartphone?

Answer (score 2):

SIM card access is only possible for system applications:

> Low level access to the SIM card is not available to third-party apps.
>   The OS handles all communications with the SIM card including access
>   to personal information (contacts) on the SIM card memory.
>   Applications also cannot access AT commands, as these are managed
>   exclusively by the Radio Interface Layer (RIL). The RIL provides no
>   high level APIs for these commands.

source: https://source.android.com/security/overview/app-security.html#sim-card-access

Comment: Updated link: https://source.android.com/security/overview/app-security.html#sim-card-access

Answer (score 0):

SEEK is most useful one,but majority Android phones are not support that.So,maybe we can assess SIM card by some other method like read SMS(in SIM card).

Comment: Hi can you please provide more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You should use IccFileHandler in interal api of android using java reflection .
It is located at framework/base/telephony