# Accessing SIM details

Tags: android, api, telephony

How do I access the SIM serial number and IMSI in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Access the SIM Card with an Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372757/acces-the-sim-card-with-an-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can get sim details using the following code

```
mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
            String country= mTelephonyMgr.getSimCountryIso();
            String SimOperator =mTelephonyMgr.getSimOperatorName();
            String SimSerialNumber= mTelephonyMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
            int SimState= mTelephonyMgr.getSimState();
            String SubscriberId= mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
            String DeviceId= mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
            String mob=mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```