# how to start Android Service/activity/dialog based on GPS Location and other events

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

how to start an android service/activity/dialog based on
1- user inserts new SIM card
2- based on GPS location stored in SQLite database

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Here is the answer [Event when sim card is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389512/event-when-sim-is-changed)

2 - You can listen location changes (LocationListener), get coordinates and check if they are in your db.