# Android SIM change

Tags: android, service, sim-card

Is it possible to detect SIM number using TelephonyManager in android at boot startup ,using Service at bootup...

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String ss=tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to register a broadcast receiver for the boot completion action i.e android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

in onReceive of this receiver you can start your service get SIM number with below code lines

```
  TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  String phoneNumber = telephoneMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Also need to have permission for reading phone number as READ_PHONE_STATE in manifest file.

you can start service from broadcast receiver as -

```
 public class BootListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,Myservice.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes,i tried that...but im not able to start the service...THANX for the reply frnds....

Comment: you can start service from broadcast receiver as-               public class BootListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(context,Myservice.class);
  context.startService(intent);
 }

}

Comment: One step i forwarded...as said,i was able to start the serice at startup...but when i get the simserial number,the program crashes...Any idea for this problem?

Comment: can you confirm that you have added manifest permission - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>.  Because I have tested program on emulator & it's working

Comment: `telephoneMgr.getLine1Number();` is a very unreliable method by the way.