# From which SDK level is android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent supported?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an app in the market (SIM Locked Notifier) that relies on a broadcast receiver that reacts upon receiving a broadcast intent for *android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED*.. I developed the app for the latest version, 4.0.3 (i.e. SDK level 15) and now I'd like to extend its compatibility to lower levels (providing runtime checks for unavailable things, like action bar or preference fragments)... The problem is that I'd like to understand if the *SIM_STATE_CHANGED* event is generated also on older platforms.. This intent is undocumented, it is not even found within the *platforms/android-15/data/broadcast_actions.txt* within the SDK.. Should I dig into the sources to understand where it is implemented and down to which SDK level? Is this a *vendor-specific* event? I have an HTC One X on which it works.

Comment: I have seen it been used on as low as SDK version 4

Comment: "This intent is undocumented" -- then you should not be using it. There is no guarantee that it works on all past devices, unless you plan on spending lots of money to buy one of each and testing it manually. There is no guarantee that it will work on any future devices. Both the core Android team and device manufacturers are welcome to get rid of it, rename it, ignore it, etc.

Comment: I'm aware of it.. the development of my app started as an exercise and I needed it due to a possible problem in the radio firmware of HOX.. I've discovered this broadcast event and it works on HOX, now I'd like to extend the compatibility to lower SDKs.. I'm not going to test on tons of phones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your first question.But i can help you out in answering Second question.

> and now I'd like to extend its compatibility to lower levels
>   (providing runtime checks for unavailable things, like action bar or
>   preference fragments)

Reflection will help you out in this case.
Using reflection you can query class for available methods,constructors etc.

Suppose you want to use PopupMenu in your application.And it may be the case that you application still
want to run on pre 4.0 devices.So use reflection

Following code snippet and bit of Google search will help you out.

```
String sClassName = "android.widget.PopupMenu";  
    try {  
        Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(sClassName);   
        Yes!!! Class is aviliable now do whatever you want to do with PopupMenu.
        // Dynamically do stuff with this class  
        // List constructors, fields, methods, etc.  

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        // Class not found!  
        it means application is running on pre 4.0 version device.
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        // Unknown exception  
    }
```

Comment: I'm using *android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED* in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file, in the intent filter of my broadcast receiver, so I can not do a runtime check.. furthermore, my app is meaningless without this broadcast event, so I'd like to use it only where it is available.