# Why are multiple messages being send inside BroadcastReceiver when I use it to detect sim change?

Tags: android

Basically what I'm trying to do is when I change the sim in my phone I want to send a message to a number that my sim has been changed.
Here's my manifest:
I have added the permission to send sms and intent to track the sim change

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
   <receiver android:name=".SimChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Here's the broadcast receiver I used.

```
public class SimChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "SIM state changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsManager smsmanager=SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsmanager.sendTextMessage(mynumber,null,"sim has been changed",null,null);

    }
}
```

The problem is when I change the sim, the Toast happens couple of times and the 
message gets send 4 times exactly to mynumber. Why is it happening? Can I put some limit to it to just send the message only once? I'm new to Android. So forgive me if I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast with action `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` is fired multiple times when a SIM card is changed.

You will need to add a logic to suppress the duplicate calls when you are doing something critical like sending a message.

Refer this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553473/1468093

**EDIT:**

The approach you should take to damp multiple broadcasts highly depends on your application for what you are trying to do. I can think of the following approaches:

- You may damp it by storing the history and checking if the message was sent within last 5 seconds or whatever is your threshold

  ```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - db.getLastActionTakenTime() > 5 * SECONDS) {
          // Do the thing

          db.saveActionTakenTime();
      }
  }
  ```
- Start a new service to do what you want only if the service is not already started, this will ensure that the message is sent just once.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(
          @Override
          public void run() {
              doTheThing(context);
          }
      ), 2 * SECONDS);
  }

  public synchronized void doTheThing(Context context) {
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActionService.class);

      if (peekService(serviceIntent) == null) { // To check if the service is not started
          context.startService(serviceIntent);
      }
  }


  public class MyActionService extends Service {

      public int onStartCommand() {
          // Do the thing

          return super.onStartCommand();
      }
  }
  ```

**Note**: Assuming your task takes at least 2 seconds to complete

Comment: Can I really declare an intent in the manifest in the format android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED with extras: ss = READY, reason = null ? Is there really a keyword extras and reason?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. And you cannot even trustfully put a check for one of the extra values as *It is possible that different manufacturers and different models behave differently*

Comment: I cannot think of any better logic than damping multiple calls within a few seconds by keeping a record of when it was fired last.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Check the updated answer.