# Anti theft application using SMS (knowing the new SIM number)

Tags: android, sms, phone-number

I'm developing an android anti theft application using SMS and I'm on the point to detect if there's a SIM card change by the thief and then send the new SIM card number that have been inserted to the alternative number so they can send commands to that new number.
My question is: how can I know the new number inserted or how to develop a code to know the number of newly inserted SIM?

Answer (score 2):

Store previous sim card number(imsi number) on server and each time anyone insert new sim card get sim_state_reciever (by using reciever for 
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED) and get new sim card number and compare previous sim card number with new one and as soon as you detect sim card change then fire query to get phone number and store that phone number on server.

Comment: sim_state_receiver ? does it get information about the new sim inserted ? such as  the number of the sim and imsi number  ?? or should i get back to the service provider company of the sim to get its number ??

Comment: you get imsi number by using telephony manager class via TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()                                                          but this sim state reciever call on every boot of device

Comment: i have another question > what's much reliable for using anti theft apps ( SMS or internet ) ??

Comment: Make your own because i don't think any app can fulfill all your condition/requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager myTelManager=(TelephonyManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = myTelephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

also you should add this permission to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

store that phone number and check everytime sim state_changed.

P.S : It sometimes sending "null" as response.

[for more information about sim state changed BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528464/how-to-monitor-sim-state-change)