# How to monitor SIM state change (Android O)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528464/how-to-monitor-sim-state-change) answer but it relates only to Android pre-O. Implicit broadcasts no longer works on Android O. I understand that I could probably register a runtime listener but that doesn't work for my use case. If I am a system application pre-loaded on a device working directly with OEMs can I get whitelisted for this broadcast and still receive it?

Comment: You should fill an issue asap in the issue tracker to allow the intent to be whitelisted.

Comment: @greywolf82 I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Open a ticket in the issue tracker