# SIM Change detection without restart using Java in Android

Tags: detection

We are facing the problem of detecting a SIM change in Android without waiting for the phone to restart. Is there a notification or event that we can receive? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Android's [Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) framework to monitor for the `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` intent action fired by the system.

Check [this](https://github.com/Decad3nce/Aegis/blob/master/src/com/decad3nce/aegis/SIMStateReceiver.java) example and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10528464/9008264) for more information.