# android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED not allowed to run by Android OS

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver for android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED and i assume that this will be called every time sim state changes. This has been also confirmed by some older posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528464/how-to-monitor-sim-state-change/10553473)

But what I have observed in Android P is that every time this receiver is called my application process is killed by Os.

```
01-01 01:01:06.764  1020  1064 I am_proc_start: [0,3334,10036,com.testapp,broadcast,com.testapp/.receivers.SIMBroadcastReceiver]
01-01 01:01:06.764  1020  1064 I am_proc_start: [0,3334,10036,com.testapp,broadcast,com.testapp/.receivers.SIMBroadcastReceiver]
01-01 01:01:06.764  1020  1064 I ActivityManager: Start proc 3334:com.testapp/u0a36 for broadcast com.testapp/.receivers.SIMBroadcastReceiver
01-01 01:01:06.764  1020  1064 I ActivityManager: Start proc 3334:com.testapp/u0a36 for broadcast com.testapp/.receivers.SIMBroadcastReceiver
01-01 01:01:06.878  1020  1988 I am_proc_bound: [0,3334,com.testapp]
01-01 01:01:07.269  1020  1045 D PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=11990847, flags=0x1, tag="fiid-sync", ws=null, uid=10036, pid=3334, packageName=com.testapp
01-01 01:01:07.282  1020  1045 D PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=11990847 [fiid-sync], flags=0x0,packageName=com.testapp, total_time=11ms
01-01 01:01:09.021  1020  1988 I sysui_multi_action: [757,856,758,1,806,com.testapp,857,channel_services_updates,858,3]
01-01 01:01:09.025  1020  1988 I sysui_multi_action: [757,856,758,1,806,com.testapp,857,channel_push_custom_content,858,4]
01-01 01:01:09.030  1020  1988 I sysui_multi_action: [757,856,758,1,806,com.testapp,857,channel_app_installations,858,2]
01-01 01:01:12.543  1020  2486 I ActivityManager: Killing 3334:com.testapp/u0a36 (adj 906): empty #9
01-01 01:01:12.543  1020  2486 I am_kill : [0,3334,com.testapp,906,empty #9]
01-01 01:01:12.911  1020  2486 I am_proc_died: [0,3334,com.testapp,906,18]
```

As can be seen by events am_kill and am_proc_died. these two events don't even allow the onReceive() method o be called.

This is happening all the time in android P.

Comment: This is probably because of the broadcast limitations imposed from API level 26. [source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts)

Comment: i am able to see that this is allowed to run in some of the cases , it is not always that onReceive() is not called, but even if the this method is being called in some cases , the process is killed mid mid way, before teh time limit of 5 seconds which is there for Broadcast Receivers as per documentation, My concern is that , either it should not be allowed at all or it should be allowed every time