# How to detect a change in Hardware(sim Change) using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, events, sim-card

How to access event when sim card is changed in mobile(Xamarin)?
I have searched and got References in android(Java) I even tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17634049/10223206)
But its not triggering . Can I get any link related to Xamarin ?.

Comment: Xamarin uses what Android and iOS uses. You don't really need anything related to xamarin, you must implement what you found for native android and native ios. The example you linked should work, but you should have a look at the IntentFilter C# attribute for Xamarin projects, rather than trying to edit the androidmanifest file yourself

Comment: Thanks @Miiite . I would look into Intent Filter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code to detect SIM changes.

Add new class file to your Android project **`SimStateChangedReceiver.cs`**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class SimStateChangedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent0)
    {                
       Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Sim state has been changed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Also provide *READ_PHONE_STATE* permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

When you change SIM in your phone `OnReceive` method will fire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I did same but was unable to hit this method.

Comment: You try to put toast msg instead of Log.Debug and check. This is working example yesterday I have implemented

Comment: sure.  I will add like you say

Comment: I tested , But its not hitting breakpoint . I am testing it like "Build app" then "change sim" . Execption throws . this method is in try catch .

Comment: Yeah, while debugging you need to open/close SIM slot. What exception it is throwing? also can you add manifest code in question.

Comment: about manifest , I have added permission like you said . Is something else also required there ? .

Comment: Only this permission needed, nothing else. You need to write same code in BroadcastReceiver class , I have provided. Don't miss first two attributes. Can you tell me about exception?

Comment: Okay So I have made a slight change I have added priority with Intent Filter . Its hitting breakpoint now and my execption details are : [these](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DWlDje_Nn9wjeLqUCXtIilqHnu8TK7Gfuz2e1RueMZY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
   added this

Comment: Ok nice! I am not sure why getting exception, you have still toast if yes may be `Application.Context` cause issue. Try to remove toast and check.

Comment: Okay Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Glad it helped you.