# SIM Watch standalone Kaspersky Endpoint

Tags: android

https://help.kaspersky.com/KESMob/10SP4MR1/en-US/76983.htm

Hi, my name is Jason

I would like to know if there is a way to create a simple app to detect and lock the app if SIM Card is changed while the phone was off or on. Thank you.

Best regards,
Jason.

Comment: may below link will help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389512/event-when-sim-card-is-changed

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.