# Sim Info from android devices

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to know the sim information like phone number,Registered name..etc from android devices throgh programatically.I go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372757/access-the-sim-card-with-an-android-application) but did not get any success. Can anyone Please provide some help...
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

you can try out this API but it doesn't work on all devices:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        simNum = telephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

other than that you can read MCC\MNC, network operator and IMEI which could help you identify the device\user.