# how to find simcard is change or not in android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In my Project require to checking simcard is change or not in android.

I am referring many question in `Stack Overflow` and many `blog` but not getting any proper way.

**I want do a simple task as follows.**

```
when simcard is change that time print some message.
```

**Problem.**

1. some of android device `CDMA` and `GSM`. so what about `CDMA`?
2. GSM which id is unique for checking simcard `change or not`?
3. When to check Simcard is change because of some phone have to require off the phone remove battery and change the simcard and some of the phone have direct change simcard with out removing phone means phone have simcard slot.

Give me some `guideline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is one suggestion :-

On your application launch (first time) save/store Unique number of SIM(Subscriber ID).

on every phone bootup again fetch this unique number of `SIM(Subscriber ID).` and match with what you have stored in your app. if matched it is ok, else sim is changed.
below is the method you needed to get `SubscriberID` number.

```
IMSI = m_telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
```

Comment: What is the problem, Why you are worried where SIM card to be inserted, let it be, just check SIMCARD subscriber number and u are done.

Comment: but my application require continue checking if simcard change then give some message(for security purpose).so question is that where to put code this code to know simcard is change.

Comment: On phone BootUp, I dont see any phone which change sim card and not need to reboot it, If even sim card is not below battery, after reinserting SIM, User need to reboot the phone to let it working.

Comment: on safe side you can also check it on Phone uses, like incoming/outgoing calls/messages, so it can be more frequently.
Register a receiver on Phone_state change action and do this check there.

Comment: I can do this task using BroadcastReceiver and Service.

Comment: Via Broadcast Receiver ,Service is not required here.

Comment: ya that's right but without start my application i display message using services.

Answer (score 0):

when the SIM is swapped(device wiil be restart), so you can create a service that stores the SIM serial number in preferences, and then compare the serial number stored with that in the current SIM when the service starts.

Here's details of accessing the SIM details: [Acces the SIM Card with an Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372757/access-the-sim-card-with-an-android-application)

Comment: i will try and give response as much fast